# Swift - UIPageView on top UITableView overlapping

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uipageviewcontroller, overlapping

I have an visual overlap issue I need help. I have a UITableViewController inside a Tab Bar Controller. I created an on boarding UIPageViewController inside the same class:

```
class WorkoutsTableViewController: UITableViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
```

I'm calling from UITableViewController.viewDidLoad() in case is the first time the user enter the app. the issue I have is that the UIPageViewController is shown in top of the UITableViewController but the lines from the table overlap the UIPageViewController.

code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   returnButton.enabled = false
    onBoardingButton.hidden = false
    if (loggedInUser.login == "" || loggedInUser.password == ""){
        onBoarding()
    }
    else {
        workouts = loggedInUser.workouts
        self.tableView.reloadData() //refresh the table with the data
    }
}

func onBoarding(){
    returnButton.enabled = true
    onBoardingButton.hidden = true
    createPageViewController()
    }
```

Bellow the private method I use to create the pageviewcontroller:

```
private func createPageViewController() {
    self.pageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageViewController") as! UIPageViewController
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self
    let startVC = self.viewControllerAtIndex(0) as PageContentViewController
    let viewControllers = NSArray(object: startVC)
    self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers as? [UIViewController], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 30, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height - 60)
    self.addChildViewController(self.pageViewController)
    self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController.view)
    self.pageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
}
```

unwanted result:
[image]

in the other hand, when I'm calling onBoarding() from a button, it works fine:
[image]

any idea what I'm doing wrong?
thanks in advance

Comment: ..have you tried changing code from your `viewDidLoad()` into `viewDidAppear()` or `viewWillAppear()`.

Comment: yes, the issue remains, tried it already before posting the question :-(

Comment: it looks like the page view controller is transparent, but I don't see how to turn off the transparency and why is not happeniing when I run it from a button?